# run testng without testng.xml file

Tags: ant, testng

Is it possible to run testng from ant without passing a testng.xml file?

I have one class with the @Test annotation and I intend that to be loaded dynamically.

I use intellj idea in my project, and I just right click on the class, but I want to create a build.xml to detach from the need to use IDEA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [nice example](http://testng.org/doc/ant.html) on the TestNG website on how to run the testng task from Ant without passing an XML file:

```
<testng classpathref="run.cp"
    outputDir="${testng.report.dir}"
    haltOnFailure="true"M verbose="2">
<classfileset dir="${test.build.dir}" includes="**/*.class" />
</testng>
```

Comment: I'm trying that but I get  `Cannot load class from file: C:\Users\oreyes\ryz\out\build\ryz\compiler\TestCompiler.class` I tried some other configurations ( like writing the class name and other )

Comment: Have you verified that the compiled class is on your classpath?

Comment: Yeap, but... guess what... my classpath is not in my testng element doh!.. thank you!

Comment: Yes, that's the correct way. Note that what you can do from the command line or from ant is only a subset of what is possible with a testng.xml, so as your test suites become more complex, I recommend switching to a testng.xml, it's really easier.